# In MATLAB's App Designer, how can I have images extend beyond their cells in a Grid Layout?

Tags: grid-layout, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to create a solitaire card game app (think FreeCell) using MATLAB's App Designer.*  To graphically display the tableau, my idea is to represent the cards as images in a Grid Layout, which would nicely handle the user resizing the app window.  However, the grid cells need to be shorter than the card images, as some cards need to partially overlap others (the image shows some grid cells outlined in cyan).  More to the point, in order for the bottom card to be fully visible, the card images need to be able to spill out below their cells.  I do not see a way to allow that in App Designer's grid layout.  Is that possible, or is there a better way to display the overlapping card images?

*I recognize MATLAB is not the ideal tool for this.  My real goal is to learn MATLAB for other purposes.
[image: tableau with cells in cyan]

Answer (score 1):

I got a helpful answer [on the MATLAB Q&A site](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2024627-overlapping-images-in-grid-layout?s_tid=srchtitle).

The gist of it is that my intended approach was too computationally demanding and it would be better to represent the cards as graphics objects within an axes.